# "Module not found" in Guile

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm writing an extension script on Guile for "Gnubik" program  and get "module not found" error when try to use a function "get-string-all" from "textual-ports" module: when I start Gnubik from the command line, the error text is printed and the program doesn't start. When this function is used in a Guile shell script - this problem doesn't happen. I have two Guile packages installed: 2.0 and 2.2.

The error text is following:

```
Backtrace:
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
 160: 10 [catch #t #<catch-closure c86380> ...]
In unknown file:
   ?: 9 [apply-smob/1 #<catch-closure c86380>]
In ice-9/eval.scm:
 505: 8 [#<procedure b5e540 at ice-9/eval.scm:499:4 (exp)> (use-modules #)]
In ice-9/psyntax.scm:
1107: 7 [expand-top-sequence ((use-modules (ice-9 textual-ports))) () ...]
 990: 6 [scan ((use-modules (ice-9 textual-ports))) () ...]
 279: 5 [scan ((# #) #(syntax-object *unspecified* # #)) () (()) ...]
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
3622: 4 [process-use-modules (((ice-9 textual-ports)))]
 712: 3 [map #<procedure c1ab40 at ice-9/boot-9.scm:3622:25 (mif-args)> ((#))]
3623: 2 [#<procedure c1ab40 at ice-9/boot-9.scm:3622:25 (mif-args)> (#)]
2903: 1 [resolve-interface (ice-9 textual-ports) #:select ...]
In unknown file:
   ?: 0 [scm-error misc-error #f ...]

ERROR: In procedure scm-error:
ERROR: no code for module (ice-9 textual-ports)
```

The Guile code:

```
(use-modules (ice-9 textual-ports))

(call-with-input-file "/tmp/tst.txt" 
    (lambda (port)
        (define s (get-string-all port))))
```

How this problem can be corrected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation '(use-modules (rnrs io ports))'.

Works for me.

**Edit**: On looking at guile-2.0, I see that get-string-all is provided by the '(rnrs io ports)' module, but in guile-2.2 it is provided by both the '(rnrs io ports)' and '(ice-9 textual-ports)' modules.

So there were two problems.  First you were trying to load '(ice-9 textual-ports)' module in guile-2.0, which won't work because it is only provided by guile-2.2.  Secondly, there was no expression in your lambda form, which just needed to return the value of the application of get-string-all.

Comment: I get syntax error: "no expressions in body in form (lambda (port) (define s (get-string-all port)))". Also, I was following this documentaion: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Textual-I_002fO.html

Comment: Ah I see.  Well it is right, there are no expressions in the lambda form.  What were you going to do with 's'?  If you want to return it, then don't use a define at all - just return the value of '(get-string-all port)'.